# UnityContainer.Resolve() throws System.InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I've a big problem. I spent all day to understand why I have got this Exception. The message which I've got is:

"The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value."

I did own research about the message and I found a few articles but nothing can't help me. I don't know which of my code to post here. I'll post any code which can help us to find solution of my issue.

Stack Trace

```
[InvalidOperationException: The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.]
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.GuardTypeIsNonPrimitive(IBuilderContext context) +311
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodConstructorStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +229
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlanCreatorPolicy.CreatePlan(IBuilderContext context, NamedTypeBuildKey buildKey) +162
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +245
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +250
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +205
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +250
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +205
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +250
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +443
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuilderContext.NewBuildUp(NamedTypeBuildKey newBuildKey) +250
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ObjectBuilder.NamedTypeDependencyResolverPolicy.Resolve(IBuilderContext context) +101
   lambda_method(Closure , IBuilderContext ) +267
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.<>c__DisplayClass1.<GetBuildMethod>b__0(IBuilderContext context) +71
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.DynamicMethodBuildPlan.BuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +42
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.BuildPlanStrategy.PreBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +333
   Microsoft.Practices.ObjectBuilder2.StrategyChain.ExecuteBuildUp(IBuilderContext context) +274
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +384

[ResolutionFailedException: Resolution of the dependency failed, type = "Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController", name = "(none)".
Exception occurred while: while resolving.
Exception is: InvalidOperationException - The type String cannot be constructed. You must configure the container to supply this value.
-----------------------------------------------
At the time of the exception, the container was:

  Resolving Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController,(none)
  Resolving parameter "categoryService" of constructor Nop.Web.Controllers.CommonController(Nop.Services.Catalog.ICategoryService categoryService, Nop.Services.Catalog.IProductService productService, Nop.Services.Catalog.IManufacturerService manufacturerService, Nop.Services.Topics.ITopicService topicService, Nop.Services.Localization.ILanguageService languageService, Nop.Services.Directory.ICurrencyService currencyService, Nop.Services.Localization.ILocalizationService localizationService, Nop.Core.IWorkContext workContext, Nop.Services.Messages.IQueuedEmailService queuedEmailService, Nop.Services.Messages.IEmailAccountService emailAccountService, Nop.Services.Seo.ISitemapGenerator sitemapGenerator, Nop.Web.Framework.Themes.IThemeContext themeContext, Nop.Web.Framework.Themes.IThemeProvider themeProvider, Nop.Services.Forums.IForumService forumService, Nop.Services.Common.IGenericAttributeService genericAttributeService, Nop.Core.IWebHelper webHelper, Nop.Services.Security.IPermissionService permissionService, Nop.Services.Common.IMobileDeviceHelper mobileDeviceHelper, System.Web.HttpContextBase httpContext, Nop.Core.Caching.ICacheManager cacheManager, Nop.Services.Logging.ICustomerActivityService customerActivityService, Nop.Core.Domain.Customers.CustomerSettings customerSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Tax.TaxSettings taxSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.CatalogSettings catalogSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.StoreInformationSettings storeInformationSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Messages.EmailAccountSettings emailAccountSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Common.CommonSettings commonSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Blogs.BlogSettings blogSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.News.NewsSettings newsSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Forums.ForumSettings forumSettings, Nop.Core.Domain.Localization.LocalizationSettings localizationSettings, Nop.Web.Framework.UI.Captcha.CaptchaSettings captchaSettings)
    Resolving Nop.Services.Catalog.CategoryService,(none) (mapped from Nop.Services.Catalog.ICategoryService, (none))
    Resolving parameter "categoryRepository" of constructor Nop.Services.Catalog.CategoryService(Nop.Core.Caching.ICacheManager cacheManager, Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[[Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.Category, Nop.Core, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] categoryRepository, Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[[Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.ProductCategory, Nop.Core, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] productCategoryRepository, Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[[Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.Product, Nop.Core, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] productRepository, Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[[Nop.Core.Domain.Security.AclRecord, Nop.Core, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]] aclRepository, Nop.Core.IWorkContext workContext, Nop.Services.Events.IEventPublisher eventPublisher)
      Resolving Nop.Data.EfRepository`1[Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.Category],(none) (mapped from Nop.Core.Data.IRepository`1[Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.Category], (none))
      Resolving parameter "context" of constructor Nop.Data.EfRepository`1[[Nop.Core.Domain.Catalog.Category, Nop.Core, Version=2.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]](Nop.Data.IDbContext context)
        Resolving Nop.Data.NopObjectContext,(none) (mapped from Nop.Data.IDbContext, (none))
        Resolving parameter "nameOrConnectionString" of constructor Nop.Data.NopObjectContext(System.String nameOrConnectionString)
          Resolving System.String,(none)
]
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, Object existing, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +447
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.DoBuildUp(Type t, String name, IEnumerable`1 resolverOverrides) +50
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainer.Resolve(Type t, String name, ResolverOverride[] resolverOverrides) +48
   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.UnityContainerExtensions.Resolve(IUnityContainer container, Type t, ResolverOverride[] overrides) +61
   Nop.Web.App_Start.UnityControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in c:\Solutions\petlync13nov2013 (1)\Presentation\Nop.Web\App_Start\UnityControllerFactory.cs:52
   System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +74
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +197
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +49
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +50
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +16
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass7.<BeginProcessRequest>b__6() +31
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerWrapper.Wrap(Func`1 func) +27
   System.Web.Mvc.ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb, Object extraData) +98
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.ExecuteInternal(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage, VirtualPath path, VirtualPath filePath, String physPath, Exception error, String queryStringOverride) +2019
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm, Boolean setPreviousPage) +76
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +28
   System.Web.HttpServerUtilityWrapper.Execute(IHttpHandler handler, TextWriter writer, Boolean preserveForm) +19
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.ActionHelper(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues, TextWriter textWriter) +483
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName, RouteValueDictionary routeValues) +83
   System.Web.Mvc.Html.ChildActionExtensions.Action(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String actionName, String controllerName) +10
   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__Root_cshtml.Execute() in c:\Solutions\petlync13nov2013 (1)\Presentation\Nop.Web\Views\Shared\_Root.cshtml:6
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() +197
   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() +97
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +88
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.WebPages.<>c__DisplayClass7.<RenderPageCore>b__6(TextWriter writer) +233
   System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer) +10
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) +71
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String partialViewName, Action`1 body) +64
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() +246
   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) +95
   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance) +260
   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer) +115
   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context) +295
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) +13
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1a.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__17() +23
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilter(IResultFilter filter, ResultExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 continuation) +242
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1c.<InvokeActionResultWithFilters>b__19() +21
   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) +177
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +89
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
   System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9514928
   System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155
```

web.config file.

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">    
    <namespace name="Nop.Web.Controllers" />
    <alias alias="HomeController" type="Nop.Web.Controllers, Nop.Web" />
      <container>       
            <register type="BaseNopController" mapTo="HomeController" />
      </container>    
</unity>
```

HomeController file

```
public partial class HomeController : BaseNopController
    {
        private IHomeModel _model;
        public HomeController(IHomeModel mdl)
        {            
            _model = mdl;
        }

        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {            
            if (_model != null)
            {
                Tag tag = _model.GetTag(id);
                if (tag != null)
                {
                    MainDataModel model = new MainDataModel();
                    PetDataModel petModel = null;

                    string sCurrentUserName = WebSecurity.CurrentUserName;
                    Customer cst = _model.GetCustomerFromTag(tag.Id);
                    if (sCurrentUserName != cst.Username && sCurrentUserName != "")
                    {
                        WebSecurity.Logout();
                    }
                    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorageAccountConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
                    string containerReference = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ImageContainerReference"] as string;
                    string sPhotoUrl = "";

                    petModel = new PetDataModel(tag);
                    if (tag.PetId.PhotoUnqName != null && tag.PetId.PhotoUnqName != "")
                    {
                        sPhotoUrl = BlobStorageManager.GetFileLink(connectionString, containerReference, tag.PetId.PhotoUnqName);
                        petModel.PhotoUrl = sPhotoUrl;
                    }
                    #region PetOwner
                    PetOwner petOwner = _model.GetPetOwner(tag.Code);
                    PetOwnerDataModel petOwnerModel;
                    if (petOwner != null)
                    {
                        petOwnerModel = new PetOwnerDataModel(petOwner);
                        if (petOwner.CountryId != null)
                            petOwnerModel.StateProvinceList = _model.GetStateProvinceList(petOwner.CountryId.Id);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        petOwnerModel = new PetOwnerDataModel();
                        Language lang = _model.GetCustomerlanguage(tag.Code);
                        if (lang != null)
                            petOwnerModel.LanguageId = lang.Id;
                    }
                    petOwnerModel.TagCode = tag.Code;
                    petOwnerModel.CountryList = _model.GetCountryList();
                    #endregion
                    model.PetDataModel = petModel;
                    model.PetOwnerDataModel = petOwnerModel;
                    ViewBag.Tag_Code = tag.Code;
                    ViewData.Add("CustomerName", cst.Username);
                    return View("/Views/Home/Main.cshtml", model);
                }

                ViewBag.Message = "This Tag Code: " + id + " is wrong!";

                return View();//"/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
            }
            else
            {
                return View();
            }
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: sample code would help. Can't really provide any guidance without seeing specifically what you're attempting.

Comment: From the sound of the error, it seems like you have some dependency that takes a string parameter in its constructor, but you aren't telling Unity how to get that value. Perhaps something like a DbContext that is taking a connection string, but you aren't supplying the connection string?

Comment: I added a snippets of code but i don't know what to paste. I don't know which part of my code can causes the issue.

Comment: Plus 1 for @Dismissile : the build plan lists at the bottom the nameOrConnectionstring variable, which apparently cannot be constructed.